# opening a second form in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, forms

I'm trying to open up a second form in VB.Net after clicking a button. I have looked it up, however, what I found doesn't seem to be working. It doesn't open the form. Here are the relevant pieces of code.

```
 Dim Output As New frmOutput(intNormal, intChildren, intBonanza, intDiamond, intPictureFrame, intKite, intCrazyT, intLetterX, int2PostageStamp, intPick7, intJackpot, intSpecial, datToday)

    Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click

    Me.Close()
    Output.Show()
End Sub
```

I have the second form made, and everything, I have created a GUI, and some code behind it, and can't figure out why its not opening

If there are any other pieces of information you need, let me know, and ill gladly provide it.

Comment: You probably have the application set to exit when all forms are closed. Since you're closing the current form before opening the new one, the application exits. The answer below will work around the problem but be aware this is cofigurable from the project properties

Comment: Thats a lot of constructor args.  You might consider making them properties so the code is easier to read/maintain/use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't close the application (or form) before opening the other one
switch the order of your commands

```
Output.Show()
Me.Close()
```

Comment: that works perfectly, but the Me.Close() is closing my second form too, how would i get around that?

Comment: Check the shutdown mode to when last form closes, right click on your project in the solution explorer goto properties (under the application section)

Comment: Can you check to see the if the code in `Program.Main` is like this: `Application.Run(new Form1());`? If so then when you close `Form1` your app will close.